# PHP mysqli query wrong result

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following script to get joindate of the account:

```
$date = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT joindate from account where id = 6");
```

The result of that query should be 2016-01-30 00:00:00 but when i use

```
print_r($date);
```

i get only

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `mysqli_query` just executes your query.

And data you need should be **fetched**, for example with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` function.

```
$date = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT joindate from account where id = 6"); 
print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($date));
```

If you expect more than one row as a result, use `while` loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($date)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```